# Postgraduate studies - public funds?

Tags: phd, masters, application, funding

I'm a final year undergraduate student and I'm considering studying further. The main issue is well, money. I wanted to ask about the existing public funds - silly questions but what are they exactly? I would like to continue study in the UK but I'm from Bulgaria - does it mean I need to check the public funds from both the UK and my home country?

I know that i.e. there are now loans for masters, but no (not yet) for PhD. I know there are scholarships given from charities and various organisations but already allocated - are they counted as public funds as well?

I found this certain scholarship that I may qualify but only if I'm not eligible for public funds so I want to check all of them before I fill the application.

I'm totally new to this so I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**: Instead of looking for scholarships yourself, try to find a funding through academics and/or university in the UK. There are always funding available for talented students; and if not you can apply for a scholarship through an academic.

**Longer Answer**

Ok, I did my fully funded PhD in the UK so I can help on this. Do the following:

1. **Find a Supervisor**: First and foremost you need a solid supervisor that can help you through research, at the topic you want to work on; and understand that money is an issue.
2. **Funding Through Supervisor**: Then see if the supervisor has some money, he/she might not have 100% of the funding but can afford less say 50%.
3. **Funding Through Research Group/University**: Then you need to look into any funding available through the research group or the university. This might cover the rest, or close to 100% of the funding.
4. **Take Classes Through PhD Studies**: Academics always help PhD students, if they need some extra cash, they let them to help them in laboratories and/or marking. This is not too much but at least you can get couple of meals out of it.

**Note On Location**: If you can't find a funding in London or surrounding cities, try the northern cities as well. They are also cheaper to live compare to London and southern cities.

**Note On Courage**: I had a hard time financially, and so many of my friends. So keep going and you shall find a funding one way or another.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I more or less have done what you have listed. While I'm still new to all of this, I found a lab which would be happy to take me in BUT they have clearly stated that they have no funding available and I need to find on my own. So I searched, searched and searched and I finally found this scholarship but they demand 2 requirements:
1. To be in the top 5% of candidates for the PhD position
2. To not be eligible for public funds
I would like to check if I really don’t qualify for public fundings but I’m a bit clueless what they are exactly.

Comment: @HoldenDK Public funding are mainly covering European students. I added a note on the location to the answer.